# Does Susy have a clearfix mixin within it?

Tags: css, gulp, susy, susy-sass, libsass

I'm starting to use the Libsass version of Susy  together with Gulp, and can see within the scss files that there is mention of a clearfix mixin / clearfix fallback mixin.

But if I try to refer to this within my sass styling, compiling via gulp returns the error:

```
Error: no mixin named clearfix
```

Can anyone tell me if susy has a clearfix mixin that should work. I see susy-clearfix but am unsure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `@include susy-clearfix;` instead `@include clearfix;`.